# Asking user's name and posting to website "Hello XXX, welcome"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I borrowed code from W3Cschools (in case it looks familiar) and then started modifying it for my needs.  Basically, I have a default H1 header of "Welcome to my sandbox".  There's a popup that saves the user's name to a cookie.  If it detects the name/cookie/variable, the H1 header changes to "Welcome (user name) to my sandbox".  I can't get the (user name) to show on the first page load but it always works on the second page load.  Any ideas?

Here's the code:

```
            function getCookie(c_name)
                {
                var c_value = document.cookie;
                var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
                    if (c_start == -1){
                        c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
                    }
                    if (c_start == -1){
                        c_value = null;
                    }
                    else{
                        c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
                var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
                    if (c_end == -1){
                        c_end = c_value.length;
                    }
                        c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
                    }
                    return c_value;
                    }

            function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays){
                var exdate=new Date();
                    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
                var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
                    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
                    }

                    function checkCookie(){
                var username=getCookie("username");
                    if (username!=null && username!=""){
                        alert("Welcome again " + username);
                        document.getElementById("title_script").innerHTML="Welcome "+username+" to my sandbox";
                        }
                    else{
                        username=prompt("Please enter your name:","");
                        if (username!=null && username!=""){
                        setCookie("username",username,365);
                        }
                    }
            }

<body onload="checkCookie()" class="background_color">
<div class="wrap">
    <h1 class="title" id="title_script">Welcome to my Sandbox</h1>

</div>
```

Comment: Hey! On first page load, does it asks you for name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Your code is perfectly fine. You just missed a single line to use it again.

```
 document.getElementById("title_script").innerHTML = "Welcome " + username + "to my Sandboxx";
```

> Use like this

```
 function checkCookie() {
        var username = getCookie("username");
        if (username != null && username != "") {
            alert("Welcome again " + username);
            document.getElementById("title_script").innerHTML = "Welcome " + username + " to my sandbox";
        }
        else {
            username = prompt("Please enter your name:", "");
            if (username != null && username != "") {
                setCookie("username", username, 365);
                document.getElementById("title_script").innerHTML = "Welcome " + username + "to my Sandboxx";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Dude, you rock... That fixed it...  I can't up vote you yet (don't have the reputation) but big props for the easy fix

Comment: @Chase Westlye: it's better to move the `document.getElementById("title_script").innerHTML = "Welcome " + username + "to my Sandboxx";` to the end of the function (delete both inside `if` and `else`) to avoid duplicate code.

Answer (score 0):

Create the function `checkCookie()` like:

```
function checkCookie() {
    var user = getCookie("username");
    if (user != "" || user != "undefined") {
        document.getElementById("title_script").innerHTML = "Welcome " + user;
    }
}
```

Comment: Arvind Bhardwaj, here's what I changed it to...  Broke the function...  What did I do wrong?

var username=getCookie("username");
if (user != "" || user != "undefined") {
alert("Welcome again " + username);
      document.getElementById("title_script").innerHTML="Welcome "+username+" to my sandbox";
      }

Answer (score 0):

Mota Chuha nailed it

Add the document.getElementByID to the else line

```
        function checkCookie(){
            var username=getCookie("username");
                if (username!=null && username!=""){
                    alert("Welcome back " + username);
                    document.getElementById("title_script").innerHTML="Welcome "+username+" to my sandbox";
                    }
                else{
                    username=prompt("Please enter your name:","");
                    if (username!=null && username!=""){
                    setCookie("username",username,365);
                    document.getElementById("title_script").innerHTML="Welcome "+username+" to my sandbox";
                    }
                }
        }
```